# How to write a script which execute multiple commands on multiple terminal windows

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, script, bash

I am trying to make a script on the following basis:

1. Open a terminal window (keep it open) and run cd ~/dir/dir/dir  ./exec
2. Open a second terminal window (keep it open) and run /usr/bin/xterm -font/size/parameters

In the xterm window, cd ~/dir/dir  ./executable

3. Open another terminal window (and keep it open) and run cd /dir/dir ./executable file
4. Finally open a last terminal window to run an executable file.

Any help/hints will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.
Sabri

Comment: I don't understand what you want: open 5 terminal emulations, one times one in another and run 3 different programs? What is the problem?

Comment: What kind of script? sh, python, etc...?

Comment: Purpose is to run all in an unique sh script, even better if such script runs at boot time when rpi3 starts on.

Comment: why do you need separate terminals?

Comment: Because each terminal opens a program and cannot be closed, must be kept open, otherwise  the main program ends up and does not work. The 4 terminal windows should open all at the same time and not sequentially.

Comment: are you needing to see output from them? Multiple programs can be opened in the same terminal(run in the background) So they are running concurrently. Even if you need the output from them, they can be all started to dump their output to the same( or different) files. then you can look back at the(ose) files(s) but there should not be a need to actually open a bunch of terminals

Comment: "otherwise the main program ends up and does not work" sounds like a flaw, have you tried to rework the algorithm/flow structure

Comment: This question should be migrated to UNIX

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/program1 > logfile &
/path/to/program2 > logfile &
/path/to/program3 > logfile &
/path/to/program4 > logfile &
```

The & will cause the program to be launched in the background, allowing the next line to be executed before the first one finishes. This will allow all 4 to be launched at the same time. The output of each will go to the same file named 'logfile'   this could be changed to each output to their own file.

Comment: Quality answers explain how they work.

Comment: Each program should be kept open and monitorized to see what's going on (it is not valid a unique output but 4 ones)  All 4 programs should be minimized or maximized any of them at will.

Comment: I meant all 4 terminal-windows (running each program) should be minimized or maximized at one's will.... sorry